# Force a new line when adding tabs with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Someone created this script to add some links to an existing tab menu i have installed

```
var fauxTab = new Array();

fauxTab[0] = new Array("History","http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE3","_top");
fauxTab[1] = new Array("Scoreboard","http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE7","_top");
fauxTab[2] = new Array("Forum","http://forums.thehuddle.com/index.php?/forum/156-the-empire/","_blank");


try {for (var x=0;x<fauxTab.length;x++) document.getElementById("homepagetabs").innerHTML+="<li onclick='window.open(\""+fauxTab[x][1]+"\",\""+fauxTab[x][2]+"\")'>"+fauxTab[x][0]+"</li>"} catch(er) {}
```

The HTML that is created does not have a line break between the li class so it looks like this

```
<li onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www27.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/15356?MODULE=MESSAGE3&quot;,&quot;_top&quot;)">History</li><li onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www27.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/15356?MODULE=MESSAGE7&quot;,&quot;_top&quot;)">Scoreboard</li><li onclick="window.open(&quot;http://forums.thehuddle.com/index.php?/forum/156-the-empire/&quot;,&quot;_blank&quot;)">Forum</li>
```

How can the script be edited so there is a line break for each li class and HTML appears like this

```
<li onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www27.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/15356?MODULE=MESSAGE3&quot;,&quot;_top&quot;)">History</li>
<li onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www27.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/15356?MODULE=MESSAGE7&quot;,&quot;_top&quot;)">Scoreboard</li>
<li onclick="window.open(&quot;http://forums.thehuddle.com/index.php?/forum/156-the-empire/&quot;,&quot;_blank&quot;)">Forum</li>
```

I am trying to evenly distribute the tabs with "justify" in my css , but because these addition tabs do not have a separate line space in them in the HTML it won't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line break tag, or a `br` tag:

```
document.getElementById("homepagetabs").innerHTML+="<li onclick='window.open(\""+fauxTab[x][1]+"\",\""+fauxTab[x][2]+"\")'>
"+fauxTab[x][0]+"</li><br>"
//                    ^This
```

so your code would look like:

```
var fauxTab = new Array();

fauxTab[0] = new Array("History","http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE3","_top");
fauxTab[1] = new Array("Scoreboard","http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE7","_top");
fauxTab[2] = new Array("Forum","http://forums.thehuddle.com/index.php?/forum/156-the-empire/","_blank");


try {for (var x=0;x<fauxTab.length;x++) document.getElementById("homepagetabs").innerHTML+="<li onclick='window.open(\""+fauxTab[x][1]+"\",\""+fauxTab[x][2]+"\")'>"+fauxTab[x][0]+"</li><br>"} catch(er) {}
```

or you could use a Javascript String newline character (`\n`, Opera9 and IE8 on windows will convert it into `\r\n`):

```
document.getElementById("homepagetabs").innerHTML+="<li onclick='window.open(\""+fauxTab[x][1]+"\",\""+fauxTab[x][2]+"\")'>
"+fauxTab[x][0]+"</li>\n"
//                    ^This
```

so your code would look like:

```
var fauxTab = new Array();

fauxTab[0] = new Array("History","http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE3","_top");
fauxTab[1] = new Array("Scoreboard","http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE7","_top");
fauxTab[2] = new Array("Forum","http://forums.thehuddle.com/index.php?/forum/156-the-empire/","_blank");


try {for (var x=0;x<fauxTab.length;x++) document.getElementById("homepagetabs").innerHTML+="<li onclick='window.open(\""+fauxTab[x][1]+"\",\""+fauxTab[x][2]+"\")'>"+fauxTab[x][0]+"</li>\n"} catch(er) {}
```

Comment: perfect explanation ty !

Answer (score 0):

just add a brakeline `<br>`:

```
</li><br>"} catch(er) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the newline character \n

`+="<li onclick='window.open(\""+fauxTab[x][1]+"\",\""+fauxTab[x][2]+"\")'>"+fauxTab[x][0]+"</li>\n"`